# Cannot find the java excutable

Tags: java, gradle, cmd

I'm trying to run my project using gradlew.bat on cmd.

I'm using `jdk-17.0.1`, but my project doesn't run showing

> "The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java
> executable. Tried location: C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOriL.png)

message on the cmd screen.

how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: First of all, it appears from your question content that you have previously had a different JDK version installed. Your JAVA_HOME path should therefore read as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1` not `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe`. I would advise that you open your Environment Variables settings in the GUI Ststem Properties part of your Settings app, and check that all variables relevant to Java, are pointing to the new and correct locations. If you're lucky, you may just need to replace all instances of `16.0.2` with `17.0.1`.

Comment: I've had tools update my Java version on me and mess with paths.  `choco`, `IntelliJ`, etc.  `Get-Command java` from a powershell prompt helps me figure out where one is located.  You can also have it list all hits, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked your "JAVA_HOME" or "javaHome" environment variable? It seems that the path is pointing to the wrong directory.

Maybe, depending on your project "javaHome" is defined in the project itself and should point to the java executeable.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions on Stackoverflow and other sites worked for me.

This is my solution:

```
variables name : JAVA_HOME
variables value: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

Update your environment variables like the screenshot below.

[image: Environment Screenshot]

Comment: this did not work

Comment: if you can share any screenshots, I can help you.

Comment: i m getting below error :Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\HEMAVA~1.P\AppData\Local\Temp\202402-14052-x04r0n.6w75\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'. Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1' must exist)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'

Comment: i have jdk 11.0.13 installed & java home is set for same

Answer (score 1):

Install an the right version of jdk and delete the other directories..

For me JDK 15 was the one that worked. So I deleted these:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16... 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17...
```

And remained with this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.02
```

Answer (score 0):

The JAVA_HOME Path should be , `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2` instant of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe` .
changing it will fix the issue .